# System.EnterpriseServices.dll could not be found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Many people suggest to copy the dll file, e.g.: http://cosmicice.blogspot.nl/2009/03/solving-compile-errors-cs0006-cs0009-in.html

But in my case the 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32' does not exist. There's no GAC_32 in the assembly folder.

Comment: And you have followed the advice in that article to not use Windows Explorer to go to the GAC_32 folder but a command prompt? If that folder is missing you have big problems.

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified. (C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices and C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Comment: [See this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1028189.aspx), hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I fix this by copying all the .dll files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 to the gacutil.exe folder and ran  "gacutil /if System.EnterpriseServices.dll"